# Store free text in Mediawiki templates

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have Page Form extension instaled on my Mediawiki. I have text field in with i want to store password information. In my template i have next code

```
{{#if:{{{mailboxpass|}}}|{{{mailboxpass}}}|<span style="color: red">no</span>}}
```

In my form i have next code

```
{{{field|mailboxpass|size = 20}}}
```

But when i add text like this Q?}6Ogcp in this field i have a error because Mediawiki engine sees an unclosed bracket. How can I make sure that such password storage fields are not checked for syntax correctness? And what Mediawiki would not try to apply markup to such fields?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the relevant part of the form code?

Comment: Hello! I added in my question form code

Comment: Strange, cannot reproduce.

Comment: You can reproduce this if you save the result, something like this }*haugub{[ through the form and then click Edit using the form and instead of the form you will get the error PageFormsMismatchedBrackets

Comment: Saved a page with this template parameter with a form, edited it with a form, saved it again, still cannot see any errors.
Can you copy the entire error message?

Comment: Entire error message is PageFormsMismatchedBrackets. Whats all. And if you type * first symbol in the field it turns into a dot. I think this Wiki engine makes its own adjustments to the field. But how to avoid this is unclear.